# Unable to save in background (redis-server)

Tags: redis

I have two redis servers running on the same machine. The second one's log files have several instances with notices such as these:

```
[50818] 19 Feb 06:41:05.007 * 10 changes in 300 seconds. Saving...
[50818] 19 Feb 06:41:05.007 # Can't save in background: fork: Cannot allocate memory
```

In contrast, the log files of the first one solely contain successful DB saves. If I were out of memory, I reckon both would have similar logs. It perplexes me that only one has this problem, the other doesn't. Any leads?

Moreover, research led me to [this blog post](https://pydelion.com/2013/05/27/redis-cant-save-in-background-fork-cannot-allocate-memory/), which contends that the issue can be ameliorated if I do `sysctl vm.overcommit_memory=1` on the command line. There's no explanation of how this helps. Can someone explain what's going on here in context of redis?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [redis bgsave failed because fork Cannot allocate memory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11752544/redis-bgsave-failed-because-fork-cannot-allocate-memory)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

As Per [Redis FAQs](https://redis.io/topics/faq#background-saving-fails-with-a-fork-error-under-linux-even-if-i-have-a-lot-of-free-ram) :

> **Background saving is failing with a fork() error under Linux even if I've a lot of free RAM!**
>
> Short answer: `echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory` :)
>
> And now the long one:
>
> Redis background saving schema relies on the copy-on-write semantic of
>   fork in modern operating systems: Redis forks (creates a child
>   process) that is an exact copy of the parent. The child process dumps
>   the DB on disk and finally exits. In theory the child should use as
>   much memory as the parent being a copy, but actually thanks to the
>   copy-on-write semantic implemented by most modern operating systems
>   the parent and child process will share the common memory pages. A
>   page will be duplicated only when it changes in the child or in the
>   parent. Since in theory all the pages may change while the child
>   process is saving, Linux can't tell in advance how much memory the
>   child will take, so if the `overcommit_memory` setting is set to zero
>   fork will fail unless there is as much free RAM as required to really
>   duplicate all the parent memory pages, with the result that if you
>   have a Redis dataset of 3 GB and just 2 GB of free memory it will
>   fail. Setting `overcommit_memory` to 1 says Linux to relax and perform
>   the fork in a more optimistic allocation fashion, and this is indeed
>   what you want for Redis.
>
> A good source to understand how Linux Virtual Memory work and other
>   alternatives for `overcommit_memory` and `overcommit_ratio` is this
>   classic from Red Hat Magazine, "Understanding Virtual Memory". Beware,
>   this article had 1 and 2 configuration values for `overcommit_memory`
>   reversed: refer to the [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) man page for the right meaning of
>   the available values.