# Redis refuses connections after a build up of roughly 24h

Tags: php, linux, laravel, redis

**Context:**

We have been using Redis successfully in a Laravel application for over 3 years without any problems. Recently, we upgraded our server infrastructure, installing a new version of Debian on a different vps (AWS).

**Problem:**

Since upgrading our application fails each night around 23h - 01h where the client (Laravel) starts throwing errors and saying

```
Connection Refused
Uncaught RedisException: Connection refused in ...
```

So, it seems that there is something that builds up along the day and fails after ~24h.

**Some clues:**

- The Redis versions before upgrading and after are only slightly different: from 3.2.5 to 3.2.6.
- We tend to have a lot of Google Bot traffic during the night. Crawlers put a lot of load on our Redis instance.
- The Laravel application and Redis run on the same instance.
- Our [Redis conf](https://gist.github.com/pierot/a2ef7c57f04033a0484641ef05c22248)

Comment: Could you provide the logs from the Redis server maybe?

Comment: I would like to, but in the current situation we force-reload the server around 0h to mitigate our problems. A force-reload also clears the logs, so I don't have any logs from around the time the problems arise.

Comment: You should probably keep a copy of the log file before restarting the server, in order to have an idea of what's going on. Also, I had a similar issue recently with a Redis server and that answer solved it : https://stackoverflow.com/a/37691326/1486518

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We upgraded Redis to a 5.x version and everything runs smoothly now.
I know this is not a solution for the described problem, but it doesn't hurt upgrading an older version.